# Build not working on another PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I build my winforms project in Visual Studio 2015. It runs fine on my laptop no errors. When I copy to another PC I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When I scroll down through the exception text it is pointing to the directory from my laptop. which obviously doesn't exists on the other PC. How can I build so  can test on another PC?

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Maintenance.RepairList2.GetData() in C:\Users\Jason\Documents\DS\Maintenance\RepairList2.cs:line 179
   Maintenance.RepairList2.RepairList2_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Jason\Documents\DS\Maintenance\RepairList2.cs:line 94
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)




  94 void RepairList2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                GetData();
            }




    fgUser.DataSource = _tb;
            //     fgUser.Cols["MemberID"].Visible = false;
  179          fgUser.Cols["..."].AllowSorting = false;
            fgUser.Cols["..."].Width = 45;
            fgUser.Cols["..."].TextAlignFixed = TextAlignEnum.CenterCenter;
            fgUser.AllowFreezing = AllowFreezingEnum.None;
            fgUser.Cols.Frozen = 2;
            fgUser.Cols["RepairID"].Width = 60;
```

Comment: The filename doesn't apply on the build version, only when an exception is raised, it uses debugsymbols to point out where it original was. 
Can you show the code on `C:\Users\Jason\Documents\DS\Maintenance\RepairList2.cs:line 179`?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: On line 94 I have      void RepairList2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetData();
        }

Comment: Did you copy all dlls of the output directory to your other computer? If not, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ive updated my original post. an included line 94 and 179. Seems to be on the grid which uses Mysql. I am going to check that Ive installed. Mysql connector on the other pc.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Mysql Odbc Connector on the PC sorted it.